# Missing argument for parameter #4 in call ignores closure

Tags: swift, vapor

In Vapor 3, in a synchronous function this works:

```
return try Process.execute( "/usr/local/bin/demo", [ "p1", "p2" ] )
```

However, if I try to use Futures and closures in a route such as:

```
router.get("async") { request -> Future<String> in
    return Process.asyncExecute( "/usr/local/bin/demo", [ "p1", "p2" ], on:request ).flatMap(to:String) { output in
            switch output {
                case .stdout(let data): return(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
                case .stderr(let data): return(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
            }
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error `Missing argument for parameter #4 in call` shown at the end of `request` in the `asyncExecute` call in line 2 of the code above. I have tried replacing the `flatMap` with `transform` but it doesn't change the error.

I have used similar constructions in the past and can't see why this one isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used vapor yet, but as far as I checked your code watching some documentations and the source code of vapor, your code would never be compiled.

- You need to pass the 4th parameter to [`asyncExecute(_:_:on:_:)`](https://api.vapor.codes/core/latest/Core/Extensions/Process.html#/s:So6NSTaskC4CoreE12asyncExecute__2on_3NIO15EventLoopFutureCys5Int32VGSS_SaySSGAF0gH5Group_pyAC13ProcessOutputOctFZ).

  It is NOT optional.
- The closure passed to the 4th argument needs to be of type `(ProcessOutput) -> ()`.

  The closure cannot return a value.
- The result type of `asyncExecute(_:_:on:_:)` is `Future<Int32>`.

  If you want to apply [`flatMap(to:_:)`](https://api.vapor.codes/core/latest/Async/Extensions/Future.html#/s:3NIO15EventLoopFutureC5AsyncE7flatMapACyqd__Gqd__m2to_AFxKctlF), the closure passed to the second argument needs to be of type `(Int32) throws -> Future<T>`.

I guess you want to write something like this:

```
router.get("async") { request -> Future<String> in
    var sout: String = ""
    var serr: String = ""
    return Process.asyncExecute( "/usr/local/bin/demo", [ "p1", "p2" ], on: request ) { output in
        switch output {
        case .stdout(let data):
            sout = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        case .stderr(let data):
            serr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        }
    }.map(to: String.self) {retVal in
        if retVal == 0 {
            return sout
        } else {
            return serr
        }
    }
}
```

This code may need some fixes (as I said above I have never used vapor), but I hope this code can be some help of you to solve your issue.

Comment: Absolutely perfect as is! Thank you so much.